# Stop overwriting when creating new df from looping through original df

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a large df, where the end column is a filename. I want to make a new CSV continuing the rows of all files who have an 'M' in the filename. I have managed to do the majority of this, but the end csv has only one row, containing the last file that has been found in the large csv. I want each row to be transferred to the csv on a new line.

I have tried df.append in many ways but haven't had any luck. I have seen some very different ways but it required changing all my code when it feels like only a minor adjustment is needed

```
path = '.../files/'

big_data = pd.read_csv('landmark_coordinates.csv', sep=',', skipinitialspace=True) #open big CSV as a DF

#put photos into a male array based on the M character that appears in the filename

male_files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*[M]*.??g", recursive=True)]

for each_male in male_files: #for all male files
       male_data = big_data.loc[big_data['photo_name'] == each_male] # extract their row of data from the CSV and put in a new dataframe
    # NEEDED: ON A NEW LINE! MUST APPEND. right now it just overwrites
        male_data.to_csv('male_landmark_coordinates.csv', index=False, sep=',') #transport new df to csv format
```

Like I said, I need to make sure each file starts on a new row. Would really appreciate any help as it feels like I am so close!

Comment: @Efran My problem is a different one. I am not trying to append to an existing CSV. I am creating a new CSV by looping through an existing one and selecting certain files. My problem is in overriding, not in creating the csv itself.

Comment: `male_data.to_csv(f'male_landmark_coordinates_{each_male}.csv', index=False, sep=',')` ?

Comment: @QuangHoang When I do this, the output is many separate csv files for each_file. What I wanted was just one CSV files with the all of the outputs from each_file on it

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call the `df.to_csv` you are overwriting the csv.

```
male_data = pd.DataFrame()

for each_male in male_files: #for all male files
       male_data.append(big_data.loc[big_data['photo_name'] == each_male])


male_data.to_csv('male_landmark_coordinates.csv', index=False, sep=',') #transport new df to csv format
```